# Problem with gadmin-rsync and cron(d)

Tags: cron, rsync

I'm trying to get the Schedule for [gadmin-rsync](https://web.archive.org/web/20110816230202/http://gadmintools.flippedweb.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=51&Itemid=38) working on Ubuntu 11.10. (The [gadmin-rsync package](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gadmin-rsync/) is also available in the default Ubuntu repositories in Ubuntu 20.04 and earlier.)

When I try to save Schedule options I get an information window which says:

```
Error: The time schedule server "cron(d)" does not seem to be running.
```

When I do a `ps aux | grep cron` I get this:

```
root       876  0.0  0.1  18976   944 ?        Ss   19:48   0:00 cron
```

...so I assume `cron` is actually running.

My gadmin-rsync version is 0.1.7

Everything else about gadmin-rsync works properly. Do you have any advice about what I should try next?

Answer (score 0):

When running from a terminal, it says that it's looking for crond, not cron - I guess this is why we get this error. You can still manually setup the cron for your specific backup (using crontab -e) and making it run one of your backup scripts located in /etc/gadmin-rsync/scripts/ (which gadmin-rsync would likely have created).

Hope it helps!

(note:  I would have liked to directly fix the problem in the application itself but the source code from the gadmin web site is not available atm)

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this thread trying to figure out how a particular folder kept appearing on my NAS. A few years back when I had originally setup my tower with Ubuntu and Plex Media Server. I had setup `gadmin-rsync` to back up some TV show folders, and never put it to use after having this same issue (the message about `cron(d)` not running).

I wound up setting up a `cron` job manually (`crontab -e`). Recently, I began backing up one of the folders to another drive, rather than the NAS, and removed the folder from the NAS, as the NAS was filling up. But this folder kept reappearing every few days. A few minutes ago I found that `gadmin-rsync` has been backing it up twice a week, all along.

When I removed a folder from my backup list (using `crontab -e`), this folder kept reappearing, so I removed all the `cron` jobs in an attempt to find out how this folder was being backed up. Low and behold it appeared on the NAS again. I wound up opening `gadmin-rsync`, and its log file shows that it has been backing up the original list all along at the times I had scheduled it years ago.

So, to anyone having this error message who would rather use a GUI `rsync` solution, I recommend you set the backup time to a few minutes out and try saving the backup again to see if it's actually working first, even if you are getting this error message.